# WebORB version 4.3.0.2 only generating C# code version 2.0. What happened to 3.5, 4.0?

Tags: .net, weborb

The "server language" selector in the "edit model" dialog only shows a C# 2.0 option?  How do I target 4.0?

When I generate the code for the model Visual Studio 2010 balks.  Says it needs to convert the project and then fails to do so.  How do I generate something that targets a newer version of .NET?

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the WebORB console is simply a "label" that says it is "C# 2.0". I realize it is misleading, especially since the generated code works with .NET 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0. The latest release of WebORB changed the label in the console and now it reads just "C#".